# Issue when trying to persist a embedded document of Map in Hibernate OGM

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, nosql, hibernate-ogm

In my app i am using Hibernate OGM to persist data in MongoDB. I have the following structure of classes:

Historic:

```
@Entity(name = "historic")
public class Historic {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Type(type = "objectid")
    private String id;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<Information> informations;

    private Double pctDocumented;

    private boolean actual;

}
```

Information (**It is not an entity**):

```
public class Information {

   private String infoType;
   private boolean documented;
   private boolean implemented;

   private Map<String, String> settings;

}
```

And when i try to initialize my EntityManagerFactory, i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ogm] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at br.com.app.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: historico_informations, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(settings)]
```

When i comment the line with:

```
private Map<String, String> settings;
```

it works properly. If i put this Map attribute in Historic class it works too. The only difference between then is one is an Entity and other isn't. Any ideias?

Comment: only a mapped Class can use @ElementCollection, Information is not a entity thus it can use this annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jorge. I have noticed this after when I tried to remove the annnotation and seems that nothing changes, the error is the same. Do you have any suggestions in how to use a Map in this case? Maybe create a custom converter, is it possible?

Comment: I removed  the line with the @ElementCollection annotation of the question's body

Comment: there are a bit wrong implementation, a I suggest you to change a bit your application structure, do you want to have a history that contain a list of information it contain a stack of settings right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `@Embeddable` annotation to Information and add `@ElementCollection` to `settings`:

```
@Embeddable
public class Information {

   ...

   @ElementCollection
   private Map<String, String> settings;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Davide.The answer you provided thrown the following exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when it tries to create the EntityManagerFactory . I'm using 5.1.0.Final version.